# Como sumar valores que se obtienen con un map en ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base-de-datos, map

Intento sumar dos o más valores que obtengo de una base de datos pero se suman como string a pesar de convertirlos a enteros. Asi es el codigo

Esto es lo que tengo almacenado en la base de datos:

```js
[
    {
        "id": 8,
        "precio": "250",
        "articulo": "Articulo 1",
        "cantidad": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "precio": "100",
        "articulo": "Articulo 2",
        "cantidad": "1"
    }
]
```

y este es el codigo que lee esta información:

```
<td>{
   articulos.map(val => {
     let total = 0
     total = + parseInt(val.precio)
     return total
   })
}</td>
```

y el resultado que obtengo es 250100, cuando el resultado esperado seria la suma, en este caso 350

Comment: `map` te da un arreglo nuevo. Para eso existe `reduce`. `let suma = articulos.reduce( (acc, item) => acc + parseInt(item.precio) , 0) `

Comment: En realidad no los concatena, sino que los números aparecen uno al lado del otro. Todo lo que tienes que hacer es ponerlos en elementos separados. ¿Puedes dar un ejemplo de como debería verse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con ese ciclo lo unico que haces es convertir cada precio de string a numero.
Pues esa variable total se define de nuevo para cada elemento de la lista, entonces realmente no estás sumando nada.

Basicamente conviertes esto:

```
[
    {
        "id": 8,
        "precio": "250",
        "articulo": "Articulo 1",
        "cantidad": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "precio": "100",
        "articulo": "Articulo 2",
        "cantidad": "1"
    }
]
```

En esto:
`[250,100]`

Y al ponerlo dentro del JSX lo que se hace es imprimir sus valores, por eso ves un 250 seguido de un 100 así: 250100.

Puedes hacerlo de varias maneras, puedes sumarlo antes y luego mostrar el valor

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect
} = React

function App(props) {
  const datos = [{
      "id": 8,
      "precio": "250",
      "articulo": "Articulo 1",
      "cantidad": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "precio": "100",
      "articulo": "Articulo 2",
      "cantidad": "1"
    }
  ];

  let suma = 0;
  for(const dato of datos){
     suma += parseInt(dato.precio)
  }
  return <div>El precio total es: {suma}</div>
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render( < App / > )
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

o también puedes usar reduce directamente

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect
} = React

function App(props) {
  const datos = [{
      "id": 8,
      "precio": "250",
      "articulo": "Articulo 1",
      "cantidad": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "precio": "100",
      "articulo": "Articulo 2",
      "cantidad": "1"
    }
  ];

  return <div>El precio total es: {datos.reduce((acc, dato) => acc + parseInt(dato.precio),0)}</div>
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render( < App / > )
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```